# Nested iteration thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to iterate over a nested ArrayList so the output is something like:

```
* 1
    * 1
    * 2
    * 3
    * 4
* 2
    * 1
    * 2
    * 3
    * 4
* 3
    * 1
    * 2
    * 3
    * 4
```

Instead, thymeleaf retrieves all the objects in first iteration and i get:

```
* 1
    * 1
    * 2
    * 3
    * 4
    * 1
    * 2
    * 3
    * 4
    * 1
    * 2
    * 3
    * 4
* 2

* 3
```

my code is:

```html
    <ul th:each="row, row_iterator: ${theater.getRows()}">
        <li th:text="${row.getId()}"> </li>
            <ul th:each="seat, seat_iterator: ${row.getSeats()}">
                <li th:text="${seat.getId()}"> </li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your html is badly formatted.  Does this work for you?

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="row: ${theater.rows}">
        <span th:text="${row.id}" />

        <ul>
            <li th:each="seat: ${row.seats}" th:text="${seatid}" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Some notes:

- You can shorten all your by using Javabean formatting conventions (for example, `row.getId()` can be shortened to `row.id`).